# Is that okay to make 2 database helper for one project in android studio?

Tags: java, android

Simply i make 2 databaseHelper in my android project to create table
the first one is like this

```js
package com.example.myapplication.adapter;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

 public static final String TAG = "DBHelper";


 // columns of the companies table
 public static final String TABLE_COMPANIES = "companies";
 public static final String COLUMN_COMPANY_ID = "_id";
 public static final String COLUMN_COMPANY_NAME = "company_name";


 // columns of the employees table
 public static final String TABLE_EMPLOYEES = "employees";
 public static final String COLUMN_EMPLOYE_ID = COLUMN_COMPANY_ID;
 public static final String COLUMN_EMPLOYE_FIRST_NAME = "first_name";
 public static final String COLUMN_EMPLOYE_SALARY = "salary";
 public static final String COLUMN_EMPLOYE_COMPANY_ID = "company_id";

 private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "companies.db";
 private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

 // SQL statement of the employees table creation
 private static final String SQL_CREATE_TABLE_EMPLOYEES = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_EMPLOYEES + "("
   + COLUMN_EMPLOYE_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
   + COLUMN_EMPLOYE_FIRST_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
   + COLUMN_EMPLOYE_SALARY + " REAL NOT NULL, "
   + COLUMN_EMPLOYE_COMPANY_ID + " INTEGER NOT NULL "
   +");";

 // SQL statement of the companies table creation
 private static final String SQL_CREATE_TABLE_COMPANIES = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_COMPANIES + "("
   + COLUMN_COMPANY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
   + COLUMN_COMPANY_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL "
   +");";

 public DBHelper(Context context) {
  super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
 }

 @Override
 public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
  database.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_TABLE_COMPANIES);
  database.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_TABLE_EMPLOYEES);
 }

 @Override
 public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
  Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading the database from version " + oldVersion + " to "+ newVersion);
  // clear all data
  db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_EMPLOYEES);
  db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_COMPANIES);

  // recreate the tables
  onCreate(db);
 }

 public DBHelper(Context context, String name, CursorFactory factory,int version) {
  super(context, DATABASE_NAME, factory, DATABASE_VERSION);
 }
}
```

then i make the second one db helper like this

```js
package com.example.myapplication.adapter;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

import com.example.myapplication.beratkucing;
import com.example.myapplication.listing;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String TAG = "DatabaseHelper";
    public static final int DB_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String DB_NAME = "yoi.db";
    private SQLiteDatabase db;
    Context context;

    //list kucing
    public static final String TABLE_CHART = "Berat";
    public static final String COL_NAMAA = "NAMAA";
    public static final String COL_BERAT = "WEIGHT";
    public static final String COL_TANGGAL = "TANGGAL";

    //list berat tag
    public static final String TABLE_TAG = "tag";
    public static final  String COLUMN_TAG_ID = "_id";
    public static final  String COLUMN_TAG_NAME = "tag_name";
    //list berat todo
    public static final String TABLE_TODO = "todo";
    public static final String COLUMN_TODO_ID = COLUMN_TAG_ID;
    public static final String COLUMN_TODO_BERAT = "berat";
    public static final String COLUMN_TODO_TANGGAL = "tanggal";
    public static final String COLUMN_TODO_TAG_ID = "tag_id";


    private static final String SQL_CREATE_TABLE_TODO;

    private static final String SQL_CREATE_TABLE_TAG;

    static {
        SQL_CREATE_TABLE_TODO = "CREATE TABLEtodo(_id TEXT ,berat INTEGER NOT NULL,tanggal TEXT NOT FULL);";
        SQL_CREATE_TABLE_TAG = "CREATE TABLEtag(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, tag_name TEXT NOT NULL, );";
    }


    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);


    }

    public static void setConfig(beratkucing beratkucing) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(listing.SQL_CREATE);
        db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_TABLE_TAG);
        db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_TABLE_TODO);
    }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading the database from version " + oldVersion + "to"+ newVersion);
        db.execSQL(listing.SQL_DELETE);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_TAG);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_TODO);
        onCreate(db);
    }


    public void insertTransaction(String Nama, String Sertfikat, String DOB, String Jenis_Kelamin, String Warna_Kucing){
        db = getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(listing.COL_NAMA, Nama);
        values.put(listing.COL_SERTIFIKAT, Sertfikat);
        values.put(listing.COL_DOB, DOB);
        values.put(listing.COL_JENIS, Jenis_Kelamin);
        values.put(listing.COL_WARNA, Warna_Kucing);
        db.insert(listing.TABLE_NAMA,null, values);

    }

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, factory, DB_VERSION);
    }




    public List<listing> getTransactions(){
        db = getReadableDatabase();
        List<listing> transactions = new  ArrayList<>();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from "+listing.TABLE_NAMA+
                " order by "+listing._ID, null);
        listing newTrans;
        try{
            while (cursor.moveToNext()){
                newTrans = new listing(Long.toString(cursor.getLong(0)), cursor.getString(1),
                        cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3), cursor.getString(4),cursor.getString(5));
                transactions.add(newTrans);
            }
        } finally {
            cursor.close();
        }
        return transactions;


    }

    public void deleteTransaction(listing Kucing) {
        db = getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(listing.TABLE_NAMA, listing._ID + " = ?",
                new String[]{Kucing.getId()});
    }
}
```

but it show error "Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: _id (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: select * from Kucing order by _id" when i clicked my listview get showdata

```js
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.example.myapplication.adapter.DatabaseHelper;

import java.util.ArrayList;




public class listkucing extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ArrayList<listing> transList = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayAdapter adapter;
    ListView transactionList;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_listkucing);

        transactionList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_kucing);

        DatabaseHelper dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        transList = (ArrayList<listing>) dbHelper.getTransactions();
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, transList);
        transactionList.setAdapter(adapter);

        transactionList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(),
                        third.class);
                intent.putExtra("Kucing.detail", transList.get(position));
                startActivity(intent);


            }
        });

    }
}
```

```js
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.provider.BaseColumns;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class listing implements Serializable, BaseColumns {


      public static final String TABLE_NAMA = "Kucing";
      public static final String COL_ID = "_id";
      public static final String COL_NAMA = "Nama";
      public static final String COL_SERTIFIKAT = "Sertifikat";
      public static final String COL_DOB = "DOB";
      public static final String COL_JENIS = "Jenis_Kelamin";
      public static final String COL_WARNA = "Warna_Kucing";

      public static final String SQL_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAMA + "("
    + COL_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
    + COL_NAMA + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
    + COL_SERTIFIKAT + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
    + COL_DOB + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
    + COL_JENIS + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
    + COL_WARNA + " TEXT NOT NULL "+");";
      public static final String SQL_DELETE = "drop table if exists Kucing";


      private String NAMAA;
      private int WEIGHT;
      private String TANGGAL;
      private String id;
      private String Nama;
      private String Sertifikat;
      private String DOB;
      private String Jenis_Kelamin;
      private String Warna_Kucing;

      public listing(String id, String Nama, String Sertifikat, String DOB, String Jenis_Kelamin, String Warna_Kucing) {
          this.id = id;
          this.Nama = Nama;
          this.Sertifikat = Sertifikat;
          this.DOB = DOB;
          this.Jenis_Kelamin = Jenis_Kelamin;
          this.Warna_Kucing = Warna_Kucing;
      }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

      public String getNama() {

          return Nama;
      }

      public void setNama(String Nama) {

          this.Nama = Nama;
      }

      public String getSertifikat() {

          return Sertifikat;
      }

      public void setSertifikat(String Serfikat) {

          this.Sertifikat = Serfikat;
      }

      public String getDOB() {

          return DOB;
      }

      public void setDOB(String DOB) {

          this.DOB = DOB;
      }

      public String getJenis_Kelamin() {

          return Jenis_Kelamin;
      }
      public void setJenis_Kelamin(String Jenis_Kelamin){

          this.Jenis_Kelamin = Jenis_Kelamin;

      }

      public String getWarna_Kucing() {

          return Warna_Kucing;
      }

      public void setWarna_Kucing(String Warna_Kucing) {

          this.Warna_Kucing = Warna_Kucing;
      }





    public String getNAMAA() {

        return NAMAA;
    }

    public void setNAMAA(String NAMAA) {

        this.NAMAA = NAMAA;
    }

    public int getWEIGHT() {

        return WEIGHT;
    }

    public void setWEIGHT(int WEIGHT) {

        this.WEIGHT = WEIGHT;
    }

    public String getTANGGAL() {

        return TANGGAL;
    }

    public void setTANGGAL(String TANGGAL) {

        this.TANGGAL = TANGGAL;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.Nama;

    }


  }
```

Comment: Java is not Javascript!

Comment: sorry sir, i just trying to make android apps and got problems on it.. i just picked random java tags

Comment: Then just don't do that. Javascript has nothing to do with java, tag spamming annoys a lot of people.

Comment: okay then.. do u have any suggest to solve my problems?

Answer (score 0):

Better to have one DatabaseHelper class which would to handle all the DB transcations,upgrades and opening and closing.

Here in this case the other DBHelper class was not used means instance was not created so then it won't be problem.

Table creation and fields are from listing class which is not shown here. Do check on the columns for the table and create sql statement from that class. After that do get the .db file from the apps 'data/data/package-name/databases/database-name' folder and open using browser sql manager to see the db file and verify the table creation and columns. This can help to see the table data.

There are some tools which can help to verify sqlite data:

- The tool [stetho](http://facebook.github.io/stetho/). can used with one line of code to use it.
- Android Studio 4.1 Added a new feature to view/ edit Android SQLite databases.

**How to open Database Inspector**

To open the Database Inspector in Android Studio, you need to select View > Tool Windows > Database Inspector from the menu bar.

Also you need to run the app to a device running API level 26 or higher.

Using this tool you can

1. Query your databases
2. Modify and debug your database

Comment: my DBHelper class is work perfectly in another activity..
only my DatabaseHelper for showing to listview is still ruin..

Comment: @KhalidanRahama: Thanks for the listing class file. As per my study on this question it's fine to have multiple DB helper classes if there are multiple database files are being created and used. Do insert the data into table and try to query the same so that this would work or else it throws exception as you're facing when you try to  query with out inserting the data. There is won't be any table would be created until there is some data been inserted as a faced the issue of not seeing the DB in app databases folder.

Comment: Verified the code provided by keeping the same sql statements as DatabaseHelper class into DBHelper and just changed the DB_NAME to different and inserted the data into the tables. Observed two database files being created in apps databases folder and could query the same.Use SQliteBrowser app to verify the database files to make sure the tables are created and data is inserted. With the given piece of code the Tag and Todo table creation statement throws SQLException as the sql statement is not correct.Tag with no proper statement closing and Todo with NOT FULL instead NOT NULL.Table <name>.